# CPU utilization in kubernetes (AKS) doesn't reach expected values

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, f#, azure-aks, .net-8.0

I have a ASP.NET 8 CPU-bound process. The scope of this process is to parse a large series of data and make calculations on them. The workflows are highly parallelizable, so to get the maximum performance I leverage asynchronous computations and parallel processing.

The language used is F# and the parallelization is based in the async computation and Async.Parallel without throttling (max degree of parallelism).

For testing purposes I use a laptop with 16 cores, 64G RAM and Windows 10. As expected, when the process is running, all the 16 cores utilizations rocket to 100%.

The production environment, instead, is an AKS Linux node (again 16 cores and 64G RAM).
The docker image is based in the standard mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0.
As for deployment, the pod is created without resource limits, which, according to k8s docs, should make the pod use everything it can in the node.

Instead I find that the node CPU utilization rarely goes beyond 20%. Also, kubectl top pods shows only 2693m CPU utilization for the pod (I would expect 16).

What I would like to achieve is a much greater level of CPU utilization to reduce the execution time (hours in the laptop).

Being the code the same, I suspect I am not setting up the pod correctly.

Can someone help, please?

UPDATE

As per comments request, below the pod describe output

```
Name:             yatp-maintenance-train-study-8mvwd
Namespace:        yatp
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             aks-studypool-35366450-vmss000000/10.224.0.8
Start Time:       Thu, 05 Oct 2023 10:47:17 +1100
Labels:           controller-uid=d6ea910b-67fb-43fb-b168-a8ccfa4c920c
                  job-name=yatp-maintenance-train-study
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.3.6
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.3.6
Controlled By:  Job/yatp-maintenance-train-study
Containers:
  yatp-maintenance-train-study:
    Container ID:  containerd://95cea040177e3b1593e6e593f979c448af783d678032a78e742aff500e5f452c
    Image:         yapdemocontainerregistry.azurecr.io/yatp-maintenance:0.0.5
    Image ID:      yapdemocontainerregistry.azurecr.io/yatp-maintenance@sha256:8a8c2f02c8106417ffd0d025a2831b142294237b9764d30a34bfa6a9648a1872
    Port:          8080/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      train-study
      --product
      GCA@650
      --def
      Pmap@Pete_0.0.4
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 05 Oct 2023 10:47:18 +1100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:     80
      memory:  350Gi
    Environment:
      ASPNETCORE_URLS:                       http://+:8080
      YATP_ENVIRONMENT:                      AKS
      YATP_AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING:  DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=yatpdemo1storageaccount;AccountKey=XzsajB+bBSls5+017BCMgLkLhVCwpVlksRi9P7iJTFDlG4PlrOuHN3yDtXfv5q+FfImoH+FinWlj+AStCaC35A==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-jhmkk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-jhmkk:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              scope=study
Tolerations:                 kubernetes.azure.com/scalesetpriority=spot:NoSchedule
                             node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             yatp=yatp:NoSchedule
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  24m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned yatp/yatp-maintenance-train-study-8mvwd to aks-studypool-35366450-vmss000000
  Normal  Pulling    24m   kubelet            Pulling image "yapdemocontainerregistry.azurecr.io/yatp-maintenance:0.0.5"
  Normal  Pulled     24m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "yapdemocontainerregistry.azurecr.io/yatp-maintenance:0.0.5" in 956.43429ms (956.443792ms including waiting)
  Normal  Created    24m   kubelet            Created container yatp-maintenance-train-study
  Normal  Started    24m   kubelet            Started container yatp-maintenance-train-study
```

Comment: As your app is containerized it does not have access to all resources on its node. Look at the pod requests and limits: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/. You also can check CPU utilization for pods with the command "kubectl top pods"

Comment: Can you kindly show the output of 

kubectl describe node <your node name>

kubectl describe pod <your pod name>

Comment: @YuriyGavrishov I tried several combinations of resource requests and limits, including no request at all. Nothing changes

Comment: @VinayB please see update

Answer (score 0):

By default, Kubernetes will assign the pod as much CPU as it needs, up to the limit of the node. However, if you set the CPU request and limit for the pod, Kubernetes will guarantee that the pod will get at least the requested amount of CPU, but it will only be able to use up to the limit amount of CPU. This can help to ensure that the pod is getting enough CPU to run its workload.

Below is a sample YAML file to achieve a much greater level of CPU utilization for your [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET) 8 CPU-bound pod on AKS:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "16"
          limits:
            cpu: "16"
        affinity:
          podAntiAffinity:
            preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 100
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                  - key: app
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - my-app
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

This YAML file will create a deployment with one replica. The replica will have a CPU request of 16 cores and a CPU limit of 16 cores. This means that the replica will be guaranteed to get at least 16 cores of CPU, but it will only be able to use up to 16 cores if it needs to.

The pod affinity rule will ensure that the replica is not scheduled to the same node as any other replicas of the same deployment. This will help to ensure that each replica has enough CPU resources available. thereby preventing the pod from being scheduled to the same node as other pods with the same label.

Once the deployment is created, you should see that the replica starts using more CPU resources. You can monitor the CPU utilization of the replica using the `kubectl top pods` command.

Reference link-[# Resource Management for Pods and Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)

Comment: Even applying your suggestions, CPU utilizations doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to solve this, but I just want to chip in with an observation, I think you may take into account the approach of K8S regarding the execution of tasks, perhaps you may want to try a different pattern such as Jobs?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/parallel-processing-expansion/

What I mean is maybe you don't need to do the parallelism stuff at code level but at execution level leveraging on K8S capabilities (launching multiple pods to run the workloads as unique instances instead of one instance running  everything)

Other option is to go for a different route such as Hadoop and MapReduce.

And something else that comes to my mind is to give it a try using Windows nodes which can be deployed in AKS and see how your image behaves running as a Windows Container, perhaps in this case the code parallelism would work as you are expecting.

Bests,